# How do I add transparency to a diffuse mesh renderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to implement a door for my game but when I change the material to the open door material I get a result like this:

[image: resulting image]

These are the settings for the material:
[image: material settings]

I would like to be able to have an open door with normal transparency instead of this weird glitch. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of "weird transparency glitch" do you mean?
I don't see any transparency in the image you provided.

Comment: Look at the material image, that's what I want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and it's quite simple! The shader needed to be `Legacy Shaders/Transparent/Cutout/Diffuse`. My shader was `Legacy Shaders/Diffuse`,

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to change the shader. In the unity's standar shader if the [render mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterRenderingMode.html) is changed to transparent then the change in the color's alpha takes place in the game.
It usually happens that the alpha change does not work when it is changed in the color palette because the render mode needs to be changed from the opaque mode for the tranparency to work.